# In Java void method calling

Tags: java

In java is there a way to call a void method from a constructor.I try something like this but get an error message that the compiler can not find symbol method printThis(java.lang.String):

```
public class Date{

public Date(String inString){

  String s = inString;

   String b;


     b.printThis(s);

}


public void printThis(getString)

{

System.out.printf(System.out.printf( new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd").format(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd").parse(getString) ) );

}
```

Comment: Whats with all the `SimpleDateFormat`s. You are reading a string in `MM/dd` into a date and then formatting it `MM/dd`

Comment: I have a question how come every time I add a quesion up here it never colors all the code how did you that?

Comment: To get your code formatted and colored, you have to either indent it by 4 spaces or hit the `010101` button while the text is selected.

Comment: I have edited most of your code to show the formatting but suggest you finish off tidying it up :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are LOTS of errors in the code as presented.  These are the ones I spotted.

```
public class Date{
```

Problem: you are missing package declaration means this will be in the default package.  That's a bad idea.

Problem: you are using a class name that is the same as commonly used classes in the standard class library.  That's a bad idea.

```
public Date(String inString){
    String s = inString;
    String b;
    b.printThis(s);
```

Error: The code attempts to invoke a method in the String API called `printThis(...)`.  No such method exists.  You should probably get rid of `b` and just call `printThis(s)`

Error: The code attempts to use an uninitialized local (`b`) and this will give a compilation error (if you "fixed" the previous error by changing the type of `b` to something that did have a `printThis` method).

Problem: It is bad practice for a constructor to invoke a method on the object being constructed if there is any possibility that it might be overridden in a subclass.  The problem is that the overriding method (from the subclass) might be called on the object before the superclass initialization has completed.  It is safe to call `static` or `private` methods.

```
}

public void printThis(getString) {
```

Error: There is a syntax error in the declaration.  Change `getString` to `String getString`.

Problem:  The choice of parameter name is (IMO) nonsensical.  What is a "get string"???

```
    System.out.printf(System.out.printf( 
        new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd").format(
        new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd").parse(getString) ) );
```

Error:  Compilation error: the parentheses don't balance.

Error:  Compilation error: the first argument to `printf` must be a `String` or a `Locale`.  In your code, the first argument in the outer call is a `PrintStream` instance.

Error:  `System.out.printf(System.out.printf(` is nonsensical.  You almost certainly should use just `System.out.println` or `System.out.print`.  If you do use a `printf` method you have to supply a format string in the syntax specified in the `PrintStream` javadocs.  (This is NOT the same as the syntax used for date formats!!!)

```
}
```

Error: missing '}' to complete class.

Problem: Your code style needs a lot of work.  If you can swear on a bible that nobody else is *ever* going to have to read your code (!), then I suppose its OK.  Otherwise, this kind of stuff is unacceptable.  If this was homework, I'd dock you 50% of your marks straight off for making no attempt to get the style correct.

Comment: "+1 but are you half man half compiler?" - invalid expression: expected operator but found `but`. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You want `printThis(s)` - the complier is looking for a printThis method on the String instance, which does not exist.

Comment: It would be best to make printThis method `private` or `static`. Else you risk exposing a partially constructed object if this class is subclassed and the method overridden. See http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=215

Answer (score 1):

You have used printThis() as a method of String. If you want to print the date you might want

```
printThis(s);
```

It's not generally a good idea to use the same class name (Date) as the JDK library class

Comment: thats what my teacher wants so yeah i thought the same thing.

Comment: for all of you that corrected me thank you very much it worked just right

Answer (score 0):

The following lines are not going to work:

```
String b;
    b.printThis(s);
```

What the above code is doing is attempting to call the `printThis` method on the `String` object called `b`.

Since a `String.printThis` method does not exist, the compiler returns the error message saying that it could not find the method.

What is probably intended is the following:

```
printThis(s);
```

The above will call the `printThis` method of the current instance.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you're trying to call printThis() on object b, which is a String. You want:

```
public Date(String inString) {
  printThis(inString);
}
```

Just FYI, it's generally inadvisable to name classes the same as JDK classes (like Date). Also the assignment you're doing of inString doesn't really achieve anything. Perhaps your code is a simplification of what you're doing but I thought I'd mention it anyway.